# Image segmentation with python

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

This for a homework question for implementing clustering algorithms. The code has already been given to me but its implemented in matlab and since I am using python I don't know what to make of it. I think I'll have to write it from scratch

I've been given a text file which contains feature vectors for an image.

```
data = np.loadtxt("filename").T
# data.shape = n,4
```

where the first two features are the chrominence and last 2 are the co-ordinates of a pixel
I have another file which contains some information about the image :-

```
offset: 3
sx: 321
sy: 481
stepsize: 7
winsize: 7
```

Could anyone tell me how to form an image from set of feature vectors?

Also could anyone point to me some on-line resource for learning image segmentation with python? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OpenImageIO is a very good place to start. It's used by many professional imaging applications like The  Foundry's Nuke and others.

As of [1.37](https://github.com/OpenImageIO/oiio/blob/Release-1.3.7-beta1/CHANGES), they've got an all new Python API which can create images in all kinds of amatuer and professional formats (like DPX, EXR, etc) and all kinds of colorspaces (YCbCr, xvYCC, RGB, etc).

It's worth a gander [looking at](http://www.openimageio.org/wiki/index.php?title=Python_bindings).